# ASP .NET MVC CheckBoxFor Helper with Bootstrap toggle switch value always false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, toggle

I am using [bootstrap-toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) along with the Html.CheckBoxFor() helper in a view like so:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.issueFlag, 
                   new { id = "toggle-switch", 
                         data_toggle = "toggle", 
                         data_size = "normal", 
                         data_on = "Issue on Invoice", 
                         data_off = "No Issue on Invoice",
                         data_onstyle="danger", 
                         data_offstyle="success", 
                         data_width = "200" })
```

The switch appears and functions on the front end as expected, but when the form is submitted the value is always false. Other things in the form such as check boxes, drop downs and text boxes are captured correctly in the controller. The POST action in the controller is declared like:

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeRights(Rights = "Viper_ViewAudit,Viper_EditAudit")]
public ActionResult ShowImage(PDFViewer pdfViewerModel, string Command)
{
  ... content ...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong somewhere? Why is m.issueFlag always false?

(I will provide more code needed, I am not sure what else is relevant).

**Update**
The generated HTML is

```
<input data-off="No Issue on Invoice" data-offstyle="success" 
       data-on="Issue on Invoice" data-onstyle="danger" data-size="normal"               
       data-toggle="toggle" data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="The issueFlag field is required." data-width="200"               
       id="toggle-switch" name="issueFlag" type="checkbox" 
       value="true" />
<input name="issueFlag" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

I have now also tried doing a straight up input tag without using the helper with no change.

Comment: Is it [this plug-in?](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/). And what is the actual html generated?

Comment: Can you confirm what happen when you set the value of `issueFlag` to `true` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view (it will now add the `checked` attribute) - does it now always pass back a value of `true` even when you set it to 'off`'?

Comment: When I do that, the toggle is on in the view (rather than off before) but it still returns `false` in the POST method.

Comment: And is `issueFlag` a property (with `{ get; set; }`) or just a field in your model?

Comment: It does have `{ get; set; }` methods.

Comment: And the model in the view is `@model PDFViewer`?

Comment: Yes it is. I have also tried including toggle css and js directly from source repos as well as clearing up an unrelated js error on the page.Still no change.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you inspect the values of `Request.Form` in the POST method - for `issueFlag` you should see both `true,false` if its checked, and just `false` if not. If your not seeing that, then something is preventing the correct values being submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately, the POST method is always seeing `issueFlag` as `false`.

Comment: Are you making a normal submit, or are you using ajax? And what is the result if you remove the plug-in?

Comment: It is a regular submit. When I remove the plugin and use a regular checkbox it works as it should.

Comment: Then its clearly an issue with the plug-in :). Suggest you just debug the script to see if its changing the `value` attribute or disabling the checkbox element

Answer (score 1):

remove (**id = "toggle-switch"**) from Object html Attributes, because you override your main ID (**issueFlag**) to (**toggle-switch**).

if u have problem with that bootstrap-toggle just use jquery and add those Attributes like this :

```
 @Html.CheckBox("abc", new { @class="abc1"});

 <script>
    function f() {
      $('.abc1').attr('data-toggle', 'toggle')
        .attr('data-onstyle', 'success')
        .attr('data-offstyle', 'danger')
    };
    f();
 </script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions. Unfortunately there is no change. I have used a different method from here https://php.quicoto.com/toggle-switches-using-input-radio-and-css3/

Comment: append (bool issueFlag) in your   controller -> parameters